# Why does dbms_output.put cut the lines in this example

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to put multiple lines at once:

```
dbms_output.put('1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 '
                 || chr(10) || 
                '1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 '
                 || chr(10) || 
                '1   2   3   4   5   6 ');
dbms_output.new_line;
```

This is the result I expected:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

And this is what I got:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

What is happening here?
Why is there a newline character before the end of the last line?
Is there a way to get the result I'm looking for?

And just to make things even more obscures:

```
dbms_output.put('1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 '
                || chr (13) || chr(10) ||
                '1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 '
                || chr (13) || chr(10) ||
                '1   2   3   4   5   6 ');
dbms_output.new_line;
```

Gives this output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
1   2
3   4   5   6
```

Oracle version:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Comment: When I run either of those on livesql.oracle.com, I get the output that you appear to expect.  So I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I added the version of Oracle I'm using. I don't get this problem when the lines are short enough...so maybe putting more spaces between the numbers could help reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are the lines in the example you posted "short enough"?  If your example doesn't reproduce your problem, that makes it more difficult for anyone to guess what problem you have.  If I were to speculate, I would guess that a combination of your SQL*Plus `linesize` and the width of your client window are insufficient for the lenght of the lines you want to display.

Comment: On my version of Oracle the examples I posted reproduce exactly the error I showed. But yes, you are right: changing the value of linesize (making it big enough) corrects the output...on the other hand, I still cannot understand why every line except the last one was displayed correctly on my previous example.

Comment: OK.  So the code you posted has a problem on your machine but not on mine and not on livesql.oracle.com.  Can you create a test case that reproduces the problem on livesql.oracle.com?  Barring that, we'd need a pretty detailed rundown of exactly what client you're using and exactly how that client is configured.

Comment: So far I've not been able to reproduce the error. I'd like to try changing the linesize to 80 (this was the original value in my case) but it looks like it is not possible to do so.

Comment: As @GordonLinoff notes below the wrap occurs after 80 characters, implying that LINESIZE 80 is set. Execute `SET LINESIZE 200` before running your code and see if that changes the result. Best of luck.

Comment: [This is the documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG099); also notice the difference with `wrapped` - with your settings (word wrapped) leading and trailing space is lost; with wrapped the trailing space after the 3 (the 80 char) is still lost but the other two before the 4 are preserved.

Comment: Also it isn't generallly considered a good idea to use `dbms_output` for much more than debugging. Maybe you can wrtie the data out with `utl_file` instead,  for example?

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with this question?  Just use `dbms_output.put_line()`:

```
dbms_output.put_line('1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ')
dbms_output.put_line('1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 ')
dbms_output.put_line('1   2   3   4   5   6 ');
```

Comment: Yes, I know this would be easy but I would like to understand why the approach I proposed gives this kind of problems and if it would be possible to solve them. Plus my specific case (not the one showed on my question) happens to have all the text inside a variable, so this solution cannot be employed.

Comment: @TTK . . . Well, it may depend on the OS you are running on and the tool you are using.  What you are observing look like line wraps around 80 characters due to the tool displaying the lines.  There may not be a general solution.

Comment: It is basically that..but it doesn't depend on the OS but on the sql server. I guess the line wrapping is done inside the buffer regardless the actual newline characters in it.

Comment: @TTK - if you have a variable with line breaks you could split that into separare strings and output each one separately with `put_line`; the line size still applies for each of those though.

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE has a documented limit of 32767 bytes per line because it is accepting a VARCHAR2.

Apart from that, it simply stores the VARCHAR2 value in an array.

The client (such as SQL*Plus) will do a subsequent call to DBMS_OUTPUT.GET_LINES to copy those lines into memory in the client. It will then (client-side) does something to render those lines in the output. For a command-line client, that will probably involve something OS specific to handle newlines (which are inconsistent between OS platforms).

Once you start sticking additional non-printing control characters in the bytes stream, you're going to limit the portability of your code.